# Unable to update the View in AngularJs using SweeAlert (angular-sweetalert) Calling twice updates the view.Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-deployment, designer, sweetalert

I am using [angular-sweetalert lib](http://leftstick.github.io/angular-sweetalert/) for showing popup in my app.

```
function _changeEmailAddress() {
         sweet.show({
             title: "Change Email Address",
             text: "Write your email address:",
             type: "input",
             showCancelButton: true,
             closeOnConfirm: false,
             animation: "slide-from-top",
             inputPlaceholder: 'Enter e mail address'
         },
           function (inputValue) {
               if (inputValue === false) return false; if (inputValue === "") {
                   sweet.showInputError("You need to write Email address!"); return false
               }

               at.user.email = inputValue;
               var ret = userProfileFactory.updateUserEmailAddress(at.user)
                   .success(function (data) {
                       sweet.show("Accepted!", "You wrote: " + inputValue, "success");
                       at.user.pendingEmailVerification = true;
                   })
               .error(function (err) {
                   sweet.showInputError("You need to write proper Email address!"); return false
               });
           }); 
     }
```

here is the view:

```
 <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="at.changeEmailAddress()">Change</button>
```

The problem which i am facing is, whenever i call changeEmailAddress function, place my input and then press Okay. 
it comes in the function(input) and i change the value in "at.user.email" what user has input.

It changes in the back-end, but doesn't update in the view. 
When I click again and then it updates the view.

I am not using $scope, $rootScope, as  [John Papa Blog](http://johnpapa.net/angular-style-guide/)  has mentioned in his blog. But he didn't mentioned that how to resolve when calling ngDialog, or SweetAlert type services.

Please help how can I refresh my view and display the latest change in the model.

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue when using sweetalert with angular.  The solution I found was to call:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

After updating the DOM.

Visit http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/01/31/banging-your-head-against-an-angularjs-issue-try-this/ for a detailed explanation of this solution.